# Configure a webdav directory outside apache2 document root?

Tags: apache-2.2, webdav, mod-webdav

My team has a web application running on apache2 that allows us to download and upload files.

The document root is `/var/www/html`.

Obviously we don't want anybody to see our work papers, so we created a /files directory
(inside the root of the filesystem)
The web application uploads files to that directory and download stuff from there.

What we want now, is to get webdav access to the /files directory, but with apache i was only able to set webdav access for directories inside the document root.

```
<Location /files>
Dav On
AuthType Basic
AuthName "login please"
AuthUSerFIle /var/www/passwd/passwords
Require valid-users
</location>
```

But this directive looks for a directory named files inside the document root

Is it possible to do that outside?

Comment: i want to keep /files directory outside of the server root for security reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use the `<directory /path/to/files>` directive instead of `<location>`.